# How to show an error only on max length issue?

Tags: angular5, angular-forms

Here is my template:

```
<div *ngIf="isFieldValid('senderCity')" class="error">{{senderCityError}}</div>
                    <div *ngIf="isFieldMaxValid('senderCity')" class="error">Max 5 characters allowed.</div> 
                    <label *ngIf="canShowLabel('senderCity')" class="control-label">{{senderCityLabel}}</label>
                    <input type="text"  formControlName="senderCity"  class="form-control" placeholder="{{senderCityLabel}}" >
```

to check the `isFieldMaxValid` - error I do this:

```
isFieldMaxValid(field){
        return (this.quoteForm.get(field).valid && this.quoteForm.get(field).errors.maxLength )
    }
```

But not woks. how to return the error value for maxlength? rest are working correctly.

getting an error as:

`Cannot read property 'maxLength' of null`

**UPDATE**
I tried this: it works.

```
isFieldMaxValid(field){
        return (!this.quoteForm.get(field).valid && this.quoteForm.get(field).hasError('maxlength') );
    }
```

but i am getting both error, how to make one of them exist at one time?

```
isFieldValid(field){
        return (!this.quoteForm.get(field).valid && !this.quoteForm.get(field).hasError('maxlength') && this.quoteForm.get(field).touched) || 
        (this.quoteForm.get(field).untouched && this.formSubmitAttempt);

    }

    isFieldMaxValid(field){
        return (!this.quoteForm.get(field).valid && this.quoteForm.get(field).hasError('maxlength') );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update you html as this:

```
<div *ngIf="isFieldValid('senderCity') && !isFieldMaxValid('senderCity')" class="error">{{senderCityError}}</div>
                    <div *ngIf="isFieldMaxValid('senderCity')" class="error">Max 5 characters allowed.</div> 
                    <label *ngIf="canShowLabel('senderCity')" class="control-label">{{senderCityLabel}}</label>
                    <input type="text"  formControlName="senderCity"  class="form-control" placeholder="{{senderCityLabel}}" >
```

Only show invalid error when maxLength error is not present .

Comment: It seems to be me that your condition (this.quoteForm.get(field).untouched && this.formSubmitAttempt) is coming true hence isFieldValid function returns true.  Can you check this once too?